# Ajax function changing css

Tags: php, css, ajax

i have a table in phpmyadmin which has data entering it every 5 seconds and a php code that displays it's content, my ajax function updates the php page so that i don't have to refresh it to see the new data, it works but it changes the table's css which is not what i want here's the function

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
    
            $.ajax({
                url: "tables-data.php", // URL of server-side script that returns data
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#my-table").html(data); // Update HTML table with new data
                }
            });
        }, 5000); // Fetch new data every 5 seconds
    });
</script>
```

and here's tables-data.php

```
     <table class="table datatable bg-warning-light" id="my-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID systeme</th>
                <th scope="col">capteur1</th>
                <th scope="col">capteur2</th>
                <th scope="col">capteur3</th>
                <th scope="col">capteur4</th>
                <th scope="col">heure</th>
                <th scope="col">date</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 

            include('connect.php');
             session_start();


                $query = "SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE (ID_systeme, date, heure) IN    (SELECT ID_systeme, MAX(date), MAX(heure) FROM temperature GROUP BY ID_systeme) ORDER BY heure DESC";
                 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

                 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  {
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<th scope="row">' . $row["ID_systeme"] . '</th>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["capteur1"] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["capteur2"] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["capteur3"] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["capteur4"] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["heure"] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>' . $row["date"] . '</td>';
  echo '</tr>';
               }
                 }
              
              ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

i tried disabling the default behaviour, replacing `$("#my-table").html(data);` with `$("#my-table tbody").html(data);` , both didn't work

Comment: Change `.html(data)` to `.replaceWith(data)`. You're nesting the new table inside the old table instead of replacing it in place.

Comment: thank you for your response, it didn't work, it generated a table within a table within a table infinitely.

Comment: That's the problem with your original code, this should have fixed it.